# How to configure HAProxy to log in tcp mode

Tags: logging, haproxy

sorry, I have no clue, why it's not working.
I am using this config.

```
global
   log /dev/log local6
   log /dev/log local6 notice
   chroot /var/lib/haproxy
   stats timeout 30s
   user haproxy
   group haproxy
   daemon

defaults
   log global
   mode tcp
   option tcplog
   option logasap
   timeout connect 5000
   timeout client 50000
   timeout server 50000

resolvers private_dns
  nameserver dns-0 172.19.68.4:53
  nameserver dns-1 172.19.69.4:53
  nameserver dns-2 172.19.70.4:53
  hold valid 10s
  resolve_retries 3
  timeout retry 1s

frontend http_front
   bind *:80
   mode tcp
   default_backend http_backend

frontend https_front
   bind *:443 
   tcp-request inspect-delay 5s
   tcp-request content accept if { req_ssl_hello_type 1 }
   mode tcp
   log-format "%ci:%cp %sslv [%t] %ft %b/%s %Tw/%Tc/%Tt %B %ts %ac/%fc/%bc/%sc/%rc %sq/%bq"
   option socket-stats
   default_backend https_backend

backend http_backend
   balance roundrobin
   mode tcp
   server k8s example.com:80 check init-addr last,libc,none resolvers private_dns resolve-prefer ipv4

backend https_backend
   balance roundrobin
   mode tcp
   server k8s example.com:443 check init-addr last,libc,none resolvers private_dns resolve-prefer ipv4
```

Between all changes I checked with curling localhost. But nothing's being logged.
But all I can see in `/var/log/haproxy.log` is:

Dec 17 12:30:39 ip-10-170-111-237 haproxy[9874]: Proxy http_front started.

Dec 17 12:30:39 ip-10-170-111-237 haproxy[9874]: Proxy http_front started.

Dec 17 12:30:39 ip-10-170-111-237 haproxy[9874]: Proxy https_front started.

Dec 17 12:30:39 ip-10-170-111-237 haproxy[9874]: Proxy https_front started.

Dec 17 12:30:39 ip-10-170-111-237 haproxy[9874]: Proxy https_front started.

Dec 17 12:30:39 ip-10-170-111-237 haproxy[9874]: Proxy http_backend started.

Dec 17 12:30:39 ip-10-170-111-237 haproxy[9874]: Proxy http_backend started.

Dec 17 12:30:39 ip-10-170-111-237 haproxy[9874]: Proxy https_backend started.

Dec 17 12:30:39 ip-10-170-111-237 haproxy[9874]: Proxy https_backend started.

Answer (score 0):

```
global
   log 127.0.0.1 local6
   log 127.0.0.1 local6 notice
   chroot /var/lib/haproxy
   stats timeout 30s
   user haproxy
   group haproxy
   daemon

defaults
   log global
   mode tcp
   option tcplog
   option logasap
   timeout connect 5000
   timeout client 50000
   timeout server 50000

resolvers private_dns
  nameserver dns-0 172.19.68.4:53
  nameserver dns-1 172.19.69.4:53
  nameserver dns-2 172.19.70.4:53
  hold valid 10s
  resolve_retries 3
  timeout retry 1s

frontend http_front
   bind *:80
   mode tcp
   default_backend http_backend

frontend https_front
   bind *:443 
   tcp-request inspect-delay 5s
   tcp-request content accept if { req_ssl_hello_type 1 }
   mode tcp
   log-format "%ci:%cp %sslv [%t] %ft %b/%s %Tw/%Tc/%Tt %B %ts %ac/%fc/%bc/%sc/%rc %sq/%bq"
   option socket-stats
   default_backend https_backend

backend http_backend
   balance roundrobin
   mode tcp
   server k8s example.com:80 check init-addr last,libc,none resolvers private_dns resolve-prefer ipv4

backend https_backend
   balance roundrobin
   mode tcp
   server k8s example.com:443 check init-addr last,libc,none resolvers private_dns resolve-prefer ipv4
```

changing /dev/log to 127.0.0.1 helped. Though the logs are not as I specified them. Any ideas?

Comment: Damn. It is working, but HAProxy does not log the SSL version in TCP mode :-(